# Running PC emulators

Tags: emulators

I have a problem running any PC emulator on my tablet. I've tried both Limbo and Bochs. When trying to run Limbo, I get the message:

> Unfortunately, Limbo x86 PC Emulator has stopped

Trying to run Bochs results in no action - it just doesn't start. In both cases the applications appears as black, static windows when swiching between running applications (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>).

My specs:
Lenovo TAB 2 A7-10F (4core 1.3 GHz, 1GB RAM)
Android v.4.4.2

PS.
The same problems occur when running the emulators on my Samsung A7 (2017), Android 8.0.0.

Comment: 1GB Ram is very little for a tablet - even if you just execute only the system without any additional emulator. The Samsung should have 3GB RAM. I would suggest you to only perform tests on this device.